# Error trying to launch application Windows CE

Tags: windows-ce, barcode-scanner

I have developed an application for Windows CE (Bar Code Scanner Zebra MK500), I make a .cab installer and the installation was correct, but when I try to launch the app, I get this error.:

cannot find 'project' (or one of its components). Make sure the path and filename are correct and that all the required libraries are available.

NOTE: All the dll's are on the installer.

Answer (score 1):

Could be any number of things, but the short of it is that the loader is unable to resolve a DLL that matches both the name and processor you're using.

- Check to ensure that all of your directly referenced DLLs exist and they are built for the same processor (since you're using a Zebra scanner, all DLLs must be built for ARM).
- Check to ensure *indirectly* referenced (so DLLs referenced by DLLs you reference) DLLs also exist (like frameworks).

Verify things like runtimes, SQL Server CE native bits - those are the common ones.

Comment: Thank's @ctacke, to run the application I need to install NETCF 2.0.cab, symbol.all.arm.cab and sql.wce5.armv4i each time the scanner is restarted.